# Not able to backup the log files during instance termination issued by Auto Scaling Policy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am having EC2 instances with auto scaling enabled on it.
Now as part of scale down policy when one of the instance is issued termination, the log files remaining on that instance need to be backed up on s3, but I am not finding any way to perform s3 logging of log files for that instance.  I have tried putting the needed script in `rc0.d` directory through `chkconfig` with highest priority.  I also tried to put my script in `/lib/systemd/system/halt.service` (or `reboot.service` or `poweroff.service`), but no luck till now.

I have found some threads related to this on stack overflow and AWS forum but no proper solution found till now.

Can any one please let me know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi, Anyone having inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I have found of achieving this behaviour is to use rsyslog/syslog to transfer the log files to a central host as soon as they are written to the syslog subsystem.

This means you will need to run another instance that receives the log files and ships them to S3, or use an SQS-based system such as logstash.

Unfortunately there is no other way to ensure all of your log messages will be stored on S3 - you can not guarantee that your script will finish before autoscaling "pulls the plug".